# Page won't redirect as no data inserted

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm in the midst of building a small forum and I've run into an issue with one of my pages. I'm getting data from a form that's reaching the page successfully though the query is not being run and because of this the page isn't being redirected. I click post on my form after filling it out and I just get a blank page with my echo data and I don't see why this is happening. It's receiving the data so I don't see why the query isn't being run.

I've added my question-function.php code below and can add the form data if needed though because the data is reaching the question function page I don't see how there can be an issue on that page.

```
<?php

include "../functions/db.php";

$title = isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : "";
$content = isset($_POST['content']) ? $_POST['content'] : "";
$category = isset($_POST['category']) ? $_POST['category'] : ""; 
$userid = isset($_POST['userid']) ? $_POST['userid'] : "";
$datetime=date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");

$sql = "INSERT INTO tblpost(title,content,cat_id,datetime,user_Id) VALUES ('" . $title . "','" . $content . "','" . $category . "','" . $datetime . "','" . $userid . "')";

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

echo $title;
echo $content;
echo $category;
echo $userid;

if($result==true)
                        {
                               echo '<script language="javascript">';
                                echo 'alert("Post Successfully")';
                                echo '</script>';
                                echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=content.php" />';
                        }


?>
```

I should be directed to content.php and there should be the new post. That's how it's mean't to happen as opposed to the blank page I currently receive.

Edit:

db.php:

```
<?php
/* Database connection settings */
$host = 'xxxx';
$user = 'xxxx';
$pass = 'xxxx';
$db = 'xxxx';
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die($mysqli->error);
```

Comment: your code is open to sqlinjection, so you better use PDO or properly handle your queries (which is something you probably do not know how to handle yet, so go for PDO which would handle that for you). Also mysql supports more sane syntax: `INSERT INTO table SET numberic_field=123, text_field="value"`.

Comment: better is to enable error reporting because its looking problem is when mysql is executing your query. Also you can echo before and after query if problem in query fields etc. you can also just echo query and then run that query in mysql directly.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski -  _"so go for PDO which would handle that for you"_ - PDO won't magically handle that. You still need to learn about prepared statements, which can be used with mysqli as well. I do agree that PDO is a better choice though, since it is an abstraction layer and has a more verbose API, but your comment makes it sound like simply using PDO is enough to prevent SQL injections. Which it isn't.

Comment: You should start using parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. You're currently wide open to SQL injection attacks. Also, you should add some proper [error handling for your queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to find out _why_ your query fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to restructure your code to prevent sql injection.

You could use `$mysqli->real_escape_string()` on each of the `$_POST` index

**UPDATED**

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tblpost(title,content,cat_id,datetime,user_Id) 

    VALUES ('{$title}','{$content}','{$category}','{$datetime}','{$userid}')";

    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if ($result) {
       //Your block of code
    } else {
       printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
       $mysqli->close();
       die();
    }
```

Comment: I know about security and preventing injection. I just wanted to get it working before adding layers of security and complexity to the code. I've added the db.php code. Even my other queries work where ths doesn't which is what really confuses me.

Comment: I have updated the code to show possible error of what went wrong

Comment: @BR188 "I just wanted to get it working before adding layers of security" ...but in order to add injection protection you have to re-write, and then re-test all your queries anyway, so what's the point of getting it working with a version you immediately destroy, and the new version has to be re-checked to make sure it still works? Save yourself the time and write it properly the first time. It seems you already know about it, and it isn't hard to write parameterised queries, so why not just do it? Better to use good practices at all times

Comment: @Joshua thanks for that. It seemed datetime was invalid and was interfering with the query. Changing the h from lowercase to capital solved the issue. I've also added security so it's now up to standard. ADyson I see your point and will write queries with security in mind as opposed to seeing them as a task to complete that's down the road :)